# Change to guest only checkout on Magento 1.7

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I would like to move to a guest only checkout on a Magento 1.7 install.

I have come across extensions which do this for older versions. I have also come across solutions like this http://www.mageroots.com/always-checkout-as-guest/ but my file structure is different from this tutorial.

I have a template installed bought fron template monster

Answer (score 2):

The solution I've found sometime ago this, but has disappear for some reason:

Edit : checkout/onepage.phtml

right after:

```
<?php $i=0; foreach($this->getSteps() as $_stepId => $_stepInfo): ?>
```

Copy the following:

```
<?php /* Guest check out only - Start */ ?>
<?php if($_stepId == 'login'): ?>
<li style="display: none;">
<input type="hidden" name="checkout_method" id="login:guest" value="guest" checked="checked" />
<script type="text/javascript">
Event.observe(window, 'load', function() {
var cb = $("login:guest");
cb.checked = true;
checkout.setMethod();
});
</script>
</li>
<?php continue; endif; ?>

<?php /* Guest check out only - end */ ?>
```

it did the trick for me